# Passing Controller Property to Handlebars Helper in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a property in my controller and i want to pass this property to my custom handlebar helper

```
App.AppController = Ember.Controller.extend({

   json: //this property contain some string
});
```

and my helper is like this :

```
 Handlebars.registerHelper('NGRID', function(json) {
   console.log('im calling in ngrid');
 });
```

and my view is something like this :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="table">
     {{!-- Table here --}}
     {{NGRID json}}
</script>
```

but `{{NGRID json}}` pass string `json` to handlebars helper and i need to pass content of json peroperty .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember has its own template mechanism. You need to use registerBoundHelper for passing object

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('NGRID', function(json, options){
    console.log('NGRID json:' + json);
});
```